# su command not working, eventhough I am rooted

Tags: root-access, terminal, superuser

My problem is that my rooted android phone with Terminal Emulator app doesn't seem to be executing the 'su' command correctly.
I am trying to execute this command, after having executed the 'su' command:

```
busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:0a:95:9d:68:16
```

which returns this:

```
ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Operation not permitted
```

I think this issue is caused by not having root rights, although I did execute 'su'. I noticed the '$' didn't change to a '#', that indicates you have root rights.

My Motorola Moto G first gen. is running Cyanogenmod with android 6.0.1

I enabled root for apps under developers options.

This is the guide I'm using: [Spoofing MAC address](http://www.gohacking.com/spoof-mac-address-on-android-phones/). Some people encountered the same issue, but no solution was found.

Anyone know how to get root working on Terminal Emulator app? Any help is appreciated!

-pim

Comment: What does `su -c 'id'` return? Which CM build are you using?

Comment: It returns nothing at all.
Also I'm running an old nightly 13.0-20151215-NIGHTLY-falcon.
I don't want to update because I have to factory reset my phone for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work for me using Gboard (Google's Keyboard), so I tried Samsung's Keyboard (use the system's default keyboard) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My device is a rooted Motorola Razr HD smartphone (also known as XT925) currently running Android 4.4.2 (stock ROM) with the [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app installed. In my case, all I have to do is to start Terminal Emulator and then execute this command:

```
su -
```

This causes me to become root and thus be able to execute any other command I want.